# fwbuilder: port forwarding incoming 222 port requests to a local machine 22 port

Tags: iptables, nat, port, forwarding, fwbuilder

I am using fwbuilder to setup my iptables rules for a public server. The idea is to forward external requests from the 222 port to a local machine's ssh port. The settings i used are:

**NAT section**

*Original Src:* Any

*Original Dst:* public ip (internet)

*Original Srv:* tcp 222

*Translated Src:* Original

*Translated Dst:* local machine ip

*Translated Srv:* tcp 22

*Action:* Translate

*Options:* empty

*Comment:* empty

The corresponding iptables rule is:

`$IPTABLES -t nat -A PREROUTING  -p tcp -m tcp  --sport 222  -d X.X.X.X  --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination X.X.X.X:22`

This setting does nothing. Does anyone knows how to do a simple port forwarding with fwbuilder ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have also have the corresponding rule in your INPUT chain?

Comment: No, I have nothing more for this rule in the automatically generated iptables script.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the problem is that when you created the TCP service for port 222 you set the **source** port of the TCP object to be 222, what you need is to have the **destination** port set to 222.  Make sure to set the source port back to 0 (start and end value).

There is an example of this configuration in our Users Guide here:

http://www.fwbuilder.org/4.0/docs/users_guide/ch08s03s03.html

Comment: You were completely right! Combined with vadimk suggestion, now it works! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you also need to add a policy rule to permit tcp 22 to your local machine. Put object that represents your machine in "Destination " of this rule and object that represents ssh in "Service". The Users Guide chapter linked in the previous answer has an example.